# Magento 2 Review & Payment Page UI modification

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-standard

I am trying to do some small modifications on the Magento 2's review and payment page - to change the image, and some wordings, as circled in the image.

What are the Magento files to modify in order to get the job done? I used the path hints, but these paths are not shown.

Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change payment method title you don't need to modify any files, you just need to set needing title in the PayPal Express Checkout configuration:

Go to **Admin** -> **Stores** -> **Configuration** -> **Sales** -> **Payment Methods** -> **PayPal Express Checkout** and expand **Basic Setting - PayPal Express Checkout** configuration section.
[image]

After saving new configuration you need to clear cache.

The image URL depends on configuration, the current URL is specified in the [`\Magento\PayPal\Model\Config::getPaymentMarkImageUrl`](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Paypal/Model/Config.php#L1027) method. You can extend config, override this method and specify new config via `di.xml`.

But current payment icon corresponds to PayPal guidelines.